# Stock fades off all day

Tags: programming

I have collected data to analyse statistically certain patterns. One of them gives me quite a high certainty it will fade off all day. Visually, when I observe a graph, it's straightforward if a stock fades all day or not (even if there's some occasional gaps). A simple definition of a stock which fades all day might be that the open price is high than the close price. The problem is it might go up till 2:00PM and fade quite dramatically till the close. Is there a way to define "fades all day" so that it can be implemented.

**EDIT**

A way to define it, it could be that the open is higher than the close and it reached its **last** high of day between 9:30AM and 11:30AM and never reached back its HOD before 4:00AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much intraday data do you have / want to consume?

i.e. you could do something like take a snap every d$t$ and then demand that it's monotonic, or make some slightly looser variant of that rule or something (i.e. above a certain percentage of d$t$ time periods are down moves).

You have a ton of flexibility though.

for example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

s0 = 100
σ = 0.2

n_paths = 1000
n_t = 24*60

tt = np.linspace(0,1/365,n_t)
    
n_t = len(tt)

ln_ss = np.zeros(shape=(n_t,n_paths))
#rr = np.random.randn(n_t,n_paths)

for it, t in enumerate(tt[1:], start=1):
    dt = t - tt[it-1]
    ln_ss[it,:] = ln_ss[it-1,:] - 0.5*σ*σ*dt + np.sqrt(dt)*σ*rr[it]

ss = s0 * np.exp(ln_ss)


cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('a', ['xkcd:red', 'xkcd:goldenrod', 'xkcd:turquoise'])

def get_trend_signal(x, sub_sample=None):
    if sub_sample != None:
        x = x[::sub_sample]
    dx = x[1:] - x[:-1]
    dx[dx>0] = 1
    dx[dx<=0] = -1
    return sum(dx)/len(dx)

tt *= 24*365

subsamples = [None, 10, 30, 60, 120]
cc = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange']
n_subsamples = len(subsamples)

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax_paths = [fig.add_subplot(2,n_subsamples,i+1) for i in range(n_subsamples)]
ax_hist = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

for i_subsample, subsample in enumerate(subsamples):
    signals = []
    for i_path in range(n_paths):
        path = ss[:,i_path]
        signal = get_trend_signal(path, sub_sample=subsample)
        signals.append(signal)
        ax_paths[i_subsample].plot(tt, ss[:,i_path], c=cmap((signal+1)/2), alpha=0.2)
    
    ax_paths[i_subsample].set_xlabel('time (hours)')
    ax_paths[i_subsample].set_ylabel('price (years)')
    ax_paths[i_subsample].set_xlim(0,24)
    
    if subsample is None:
        label = 'no subsampling'
    else:
        label = f'subsampled every {subsample} minutes'
    ax_hist.hist(signals, bins=np.arange(-1,1,0.05), label=label, alpha=0.5, facecolor=cc[i_subsample], density=True)

ax_hist.set_xlabel('signal')
ax_hist.legend()
    

    
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Where the code montecarlos some prices intraday, and then takes the difference of prices through the day, then coutns a positive difference as a 1 and a negative difference as a -1, and takes the mean of all the values, subsampled at different intervals, and then colours the paths based on the signal strength. You can clearly see that if you sample too many times, your samples all end up averaging out to zero, while if you sample less frequently you get a stronger signal.

Comment: I am using 5 and 1 minute candlesticks. I think I have a rough idea of what you mean. Could you elaborate on the way to do that? What do you mean by snap?

Comment: snap = an observation of the stock price at a specified time, so for example you coud look at the price each hour and check that it is not above the previous price

Comment: If you can elaborate, I will accept your answer. How would you do that step by step?

Comment: @David - is anything about my answer not clear?